# Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

The line in question appears to be just

```
Parser2.Parse("E:\\Dropbox\\Sch\\CS3201\\Assignments\\SIMPLE.txt");
```

Defined in an include file

```
#include "Parser2.cpp"
```

---

**[Full Source](http://pastie.org/5127649)**

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Parser2.Parse(@"E:\Dropbox\Sch\CS3201\Assignments\SIMPLE.txt");

Comment: @Rolice: You're thinking of C#.

Comment: @Rolice: Since when is that a valid character in that position in C++?

Comment: @Jiew: BTW it's weird to `#include` .cpp files. Did you mean for the class definition to be in a file `Parser2.hpp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Parse` is a static method, so you need

```
Parser2::Parse("E:\\Dropbox\\Sch\\CS3201\\Assignments\\SIMPLE.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Parser2::Parse as it's static method.